# Connection string in VS 2015

Tags: c#

Sorry if this is a really simple question, but I swear I have a)stared at it for a couple of days, and b) tried to google the answer.

I am using Visual Studio 2015, and I have added a database called Investments 4.  I can connect to it using table adapters and a data grid and display data.

In another part of the program I am exploring SQL commands and trying to open the connection manually and then read data.  I am trying to set up a new SqlConnection and I have picked up the connection string by right clicking the database in Server explorer and looking in properties which gives me the connection string.

However.... When I paste this connection string into the new instance command, VS objects because it contains quotation marks and backslashes.

Here's the line.

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = "C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Investments 4.mdf"; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
myConnection.Open();
```

Clearly something simple and obvious wrong, but if someone could spare a couple of minutes to guide me, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Add `@` at start of such string.

Comment: VS is trying to escape the string you have input into `SqlConnection()` Use a @ at the beginning i.e `SqlConnection(@"SomeString")`

Comment: I'm not sure you need those double quotes in the connection string anyway.

Comment: You should check out the SqlConnectionStringBuilder class. Very useful!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to escape the string.  You can do so using the `@` prefix:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = ""C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Investments 4.mdf""; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30")
```

which means you just need to double up instances of `"`.  Without using the `@` prefix, you need to escape all the double quotes using the `\` character, which also needs to be escaped itself:

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = \"C:\\Users\\Nick\\Documents\\Investments 4.mdf\"; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30")
```

When dealing with strings with file paths in - it's usually preferred to use the `@` prefix.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the double inverted commas at the file path in your connection string as follow :

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Investments 4.mdf; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
myConnection.Open();
```

All as same.. as you have

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! When you want to express code in a post, please put 4 spaces before each line, or simply hit `Ctrl+K` !