# Connection error c# sqlexpress

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

I have a c# project wit SQL express database.
It works on my PC, but doesn't work in client PC and following error is 52&26.

How can I write a connection string to work on my PC and work on other PC's?

Comment: Can you post the full exception message please

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Also please provide your connection string

Answer (score 0):

Use common Server for handling SQL Database. If your application is not developed for common Database Server system then you should replace your SQL instance name in the connection string with Client PC SQL instance name before deployment/creating setup file. Use App.config file for establishing connection with SQL.
like below..

```xml
<add name="Yourconnectionname" connectionString="Database=YourDBname;Server=Change with Client Server Instane name;UID=clientid;PWD=clientpwd;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: did you save the same db file to the exact location on other PC as mentioned in connection string?
Also check this may be helpful in your case [LocalDB connection string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504703/connection-string-in-vs-2015)